# Why my program terminates (using pipes)?

Tags: shell, pipe, exec, fork

I want to make a shell that can use pipes. When I use this code to run a pipe in my shell even though everything is in a WHILE(1) loop my shell terminates. Why? Is there a problem with the use of the `dup` function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(void)
{


  int pfds[2];
  pipe(pfds);
  char *ar1;
  const char sp = ' ';
  int temp, temp1, temp2, acc;
  int i, j;
  int t = 0;
  char *line=(char *) malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
  char *frsarg=(char *) malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
  char *firstcmd=(char *) malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
  char *seccmd=(char *) malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
  char *scmd=(char *) malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
  char *secondcmd=(char *) malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
  char *secarg=(char *) malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
  char *frscmd=(char *) malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
  char *cmd1=(char *) malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
  char *cmd=(char *) malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
  char *cmdf=(char *) malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
  char *arg1=(char *) malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
  char *allarg=(char *) malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
  char *arg2=(char *) malloc(1024*sizeof(char)); 
  char *arg3=(char *) malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
while (1) {
       /* Ektypwse to command prompt */
       printf("$ ");
       fflush(stdout);                            



       fgets(line, 1024, stdin);                  //Reads the command.


       for(i=0;i<1024;i++){

           if(line[i]=='\n')                      //Deletes the "Enter" from the end of the string.
             {
               line[i]='\0';                      //Replace "Enter" with \0.

             }
          if(line[i] == 'e' && line[i+1] == 'x' && line[i+2] == 'i' && line[i+3] == 't' ) {
           exit(1);
          }


        }

   seccmd = strchr(line, '|'); 
   acc = 0;
    for(i=0;i<1024;i++){ 
       if(line[i]=='|'){
         acc = i;   
         t=t+1; 
        }                    //Finds the second space.
    }





/*FIRST COMMAND AND ARGUMENT*/

if(acc != 0 ){
       //printf("OKIF\n");                         
       for(j=0;j<acc;j++){
          //printf("OKFOR\n");                     
          frscmd[j]= line[j];                         
       }
      //printf("FIRST COMMAND %s\n", frscmd);                  
    }
 /*FIRST ARG*/
 frsarg = strchr(frscmd, sp);
    if(frsarg != NULL){
          while(isspace(*frsarg)) ++frsarg;                
    }

    for (i=0;i<1024;i++){
        if (frsarg[i] == ' '){
        frsarg[i] = '\0';
        }
    }


 /*FIRST COMMAND*/


 acc = 0;
 for(i=0;i<1024;i++){ 
       if(frscmd[i]==' '){
         acc = i;   
         break;
        }  

  }

 if(acc != 0 ){
       //printf("OKIF\n");                         
       for(j=0;j<acc;j++){
          //printf("OKFOR\n");                     
          firstcmd[j]= frscmd[j];                         
       }

 }
 if(firstcmd != NULL){
       while(isspace(*firstcmd)) ++firstcmd;  
 }
 printf("FIRST COMMAND TEST %s TEST\n", firstcmd);  
 printf("FIRST ARGUMENT TEST %s TEST\n", frsarg);

// firstcmd == "ls" ,frsarg == "-l"

/*SECOND COMMAND AND ARGUMENTS */

//seccmd = " | ws -l



//SECOND COMMAND WITHOUT "|" secondcmd = _wc_-l


secondcmd = strchr(seccmd, sp);
    if(secondcmd != NULL){
          while(isspace(*secondcmd)) ++secondcmd;                
    }



//SECCOND COMMAND scmd


 acc = 0;
 for(i=0;i<1024;i++){ 
       if(secondcmd[i]==' '){
         acc = i+1;   

        }  

  }

 if(acc != 0 ){

       for(j=0;j<acc;j++){

          scmd[j]= secondcmd[j];                         
       }

 }

for (i=0;i<1024;i++){
        if (scmd[i] == ' '){
        scmd[i] = '\0';
        }
    }

 printf("SECOND COMMAND TEST %s TEST\n", scmd);  

//SECOND ARGUMENT secarg


secarg = strchr(secondcmd, sp);
if(secarg != NULL){
          while(isspace(*secarg)) ++secarg;                
    }


printf("SECOND ARGUMENT TEST %s TEST\n", secarg);  


//FIRST COMMAND = firstcmd____FIRST ARGUMENT = frsarg_____SECOND COMMAND = scmd_____SECOND ARGUMENT = secarg

if (!fork()) {
        close(1);       /* close normal stdout */
        dup(pfds[1]);   /* make stdout same as pfds[1] */
        close(pfds[0]); /* we don't need this */
        execlp(firstcmd, firstcmd, frsarg,(char*) NULL);
    } else {
        close(0);       /* close normal stdin */
        dup(pfds[0]);   /* make stdin same as pfds[0] */
        close(pfds[1]); /* we don't need this */
        execlp(scmd, scmd, secarg,(char*) NULL);
    }

   return 0;


}
}
```

Comment: Please edit to show a working shell script that calls this program.

Comment: Your basic pipe/fork/exec code seems OK.  What happens after those `exec` calls is anybody's guess.  The code has multiple potential problems and is beyond the scope of the Unix & Linux stack exchange site.

Comment: Your shell does a fork and then both parent and child do an execlp. This will replace the shell with scmd, and that while loop will cease to exist. A shell would normally have the parent of a fork do a waitpid, not an exec.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Can you please show me the changes that i have to do. I am very new to software coding so there are many things that i have to understand how they work before i will be able to solve problems like this one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: i want to make a shell that use pipes to execute commands like "ls -l | wc -l" This is what i have to do. I have succeded in parsing the command given by the user but i can not make the pipe

Comment: Learn how to debug.  Make an educated guess as to what part of your program is failing; then delete irrelevant parts and retest.  Repeat.  If the problem goes away, the code you just deleted is probably (at last partly) responsible.  If you reach a point where you can't cut any more, you've narrowed down the problem.  And finally, when you post your minimal example code to Stack Exchange, ***indent it properly!***  P.S. If you think you're writing a shell, don't just say "my shell terminates" without clarifying that, when you say "my shell", you mean the program you're writing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a very long and complex piece of code, and the logic seems
rather *ad hoc*. It would take me way too long to dissect the whole
thing.

I do observe that you `fork()` only once, and each branch then calls
`execlp()` to run one of the two processes in your pipeline. That leaves
no process continuing to run the shell. So you really need to `fork()`
twice.

Let's say that the original process is `A`. After the first call to
`fork()` we have original process `A` and child `A1`. `A` then calls
`wait()` to pause until `A1` terminates. `A1` calls `fork()` again and
runs the pipelined commands.

Or something like that. Looking at my code bank, I see the last time I
experimented with this stuff was in 2000, and I wasn't doing two
subprocesses as you are. But this should be a step in the right
direction, anyway.